# Recovering account access for Joomla

Tags: wordpress, security, joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5

I have a very odd situation. I need to access Joomla (2.5) backend, but I do not have a password for accessing the back end, nor do I have the password for the database, web hosting and I do not have access to FTP so I can not look into the config file.

*It is for a 100% legitimate reason. Note that I tagged Wordpress: this is because it is a theoretical thing and they work in same ways it might help reach out to hidden answers*

Generally asking how to "hack" or gain access to Joomla is obviously bad. In this case I have been approached by a company boss who needs access to see what a certain someone has been up to, but only that someone has passwords (I know, bad) and asking for those passwords may cause them to destroy the evidence. Just to make it clear, this isn't a legal or moral question - this is genuine and it is nothing illegal so law enforcement is irrelevant it is an interal "have you been doing your job".

**So as with all questions, what have I tried:**

All the obvious passwords/usernames

Tried all ways I can think of to gain access to the Database (that's what I need)

Looking for the email which can be sent when Joomla is setup with login info - no luck yet

And a few other things as mentioned in paragraph 1

**The question**

Is there somewhere else the password maybe stored, like (but not) the config file. Is there anything without FTP access I can do? Has anyone had this sort of problem before? Has anyone got a brainwave I haven't had?

Ps. Once I'm in that is all that matters, I will have everything I need and they can find out someone else has been in if for example a system email is sent to them because of something I do.

Just to reiterate as I don't want this to be taken the wrong way: *I'm not hacking, I'm recovering data.*

Comment: without any of those, i think your only solution would be to try to find a new hole in joomla and hack it, or if it's an older version, to use some of the existing exploits....

Comment: @MarkoD That's what I thought. Have to see if anyone else comes up with anything

Comment: well, if you have access to the computer that joomla admin uses, you can install keylogger to find out the password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important question to ask yourself is:

*What makes my position different than position of any site visitor?*

If you can't access the site by any technical means, you may try contacting web hosting on the behalf of the company, providing legal info about the ownership and/ or explaining the  problem.

*Hint: domain might be registered for the company/ company boss,
or the invoices for hosting might be issued on the company*

There might be ways how to hack into Joomla, but any real administrator should notice that and as I understand this is what you want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The only place that a user's password is stored in Joomla is in the user's record in the DB. If you can't access the admin or the DB, then the only other way is to have access to the user's email address so you can use the built in password reset.

If you have access to the user's email address, then simply use this URL to reset the password:

http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php?option=com_users&view=reset

If you do not have access to the DB, the admin, or the user's email address, then you are out of luck. You would have to find an actual security issue in Joomla and exploit that to gain control of the site.

Answer (score -1):

This page should get you everything you need:

http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F

It covers using a trick with the config file to editing the database. It takes an understanding of PhpMyAdmin, but if you follow the directions you'll probably be fine.

EDIT: I just re-read your post. Is there a reason you don't have access to the web host to get into the database? Short of the reset password (guessing a bunch of old emails) this is the only way to reset it.

Comment: Hi as I said I don't have access to the Config file and reason for this is I do not have passwords, and the more detailed reason is due to poor management and control of the company but that has created this job so can't really complain :)

Answer (score -1):

Well the whole concept is ridiculous but I'd find a blog post somewhere that says how important it is for there never to be a situation in which only one person has the admin information for your website, that is the bus factor. Then I'd have the boss email the person with access a link to that article and say "If anything happened to you we'd be in big trouble, we better take care of this. Send x a copy of all of the relevant passwords and access codes for safe keeping."

Comment: I agree and I would love too. But he knows he is doing stuff wrong at the point is we need evidence before it is destroyed. Just to stress this is not one of my sites! Think the company in question has learnt it's lesson